# Run script on remote SUSE Linux with root privilege using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: linux, powershell, winscp, suse, winscp-net

I'm trying to execute `sh` script from Windows on Remote SUSE Linux  using WinSCP .NET assembly.

I've created a session as follow:

```
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @
{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "RemoteIp"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
}
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
```

I run the `sh` script

```
$session.ExecuteCommand("bash /home/script.sh" )
```

and I get permissions errors, for example:

> rm: cannot remove '/somefolder': Permission denied.

Simple command like `uname` works fine.

Any idea how can I log in as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run your command through `sudo`:

```
$session.ExecuteCommand("sudo bash /home/script.sh")
```

Though WinSCP does not support providing input to commands. So your remote system must be configured not to require `sudo` password (at all, or for that specific command).

Some references:

- [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)
- [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your WinSCP profile (Session > Sites > Site Manager)

Click on Edit > Advanced... > Environment > SFTP

Insert sudo su -c /usr/lib/sftp-server in "SFTP Server" (note this path might be different in your system)

Save and connect

Comment: thanks for your  answer, is it possible to do it automatically? by runnig some command?

Comment: no idea about this but you can add manually.